# mySqli ....inner join?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables..photos and galleries with the following structure:
-----------------------------------------------
Table: photos
-----------------------------------------------
--photo ----- owner -  gallery - order
123.jpg --------23--------28 ------ 1
234.jpg  --------23--------28 ------ 2
345.jpg  --------23--------29 ------ 1
456.jpg --------23--------29 ------ 2
567.jpg --------23--------30 ------ 1

------------------------------------------------
Table: galleries
-----------------------------------------------
id --galleryname ---- owner ---- access - 
28 -- Gallery 1 ---------- 23 ------- private - 
 
29 -- Gallery 2 ---------- 23 ------- public - 
30 -- Gallery 3 ---------- 23 ------- public -

The relation between the two tables is that photos.gallery =  galleries.id

I want to get a list (using a while loop) of every gallery with a specific access type (private) and get the photos.photo from the photos table for each gallery where the order = 1.

Should I be using an inner join, left join or what?  I tried the below and it did not work.  Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT galleries.id, galleries.galleryname, photos.photo FROM galleries INNER JOIN photos ON galleries.id=photos.gallery WHERE galleries.access = 'private' AND galleries.owner = '23' AND photos.count = '1'")) 
{     
  $stmt->execute();     
  $stmt->bind_result($private_gal_id,$private_gal_name,$private_gal_photo);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {      
      echo "The results: $private_gal_id - $private_gal_name - $private_gal_photo";
    }
  $stmt->close();;
}
```

Comment: JFYI: mysqli is a driver name, not database server name. it has nothing to do with joins or whatever else SQL syntax. You're still using regular mysql syntax for this.

Comment: In an unrelated note: Format your code. Horizontal scrolling is evil. SQL can be broken across several lines and indented, even in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the education on my comment.

Comment: Tomalak...thanks to you too.  I am just starting to learn to write clean code.  I will start to format that way...especially when asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

`AND photos.count = '1'"))`

at the end of the query it should be:

`AND photos.order = '1'"))`

Comment: You beat me to it. I must add that testing this query in PHP admin or another MySQL client would have helped find the issue.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Working now.  Thank you.