# Join two queries from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

How can I join those two queries into one?

The first query getting all posts_id from specific category; postId from post_category table equals to id in post table

```
select distinct postId 
  from post_category 
  where categoryId='125' or categoryId='3'
```

then I want to join them so it will select all postId from post_category in post table

```
SELECT * FROM post <<query one join>> AND approve=1"
```

post

```
  +--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | id           | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
    | autor        | varchar(40)           | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | date         | datetime              | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
    | short_story  | text                  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
    | full_story   | text                  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
    | xfields      | text                  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | title        | varchar(255)          | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | descr        | varchar(200)          | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | keywords     | text                  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | category     | varchar(200)          | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    | alt_name     | varchar(200)          | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | comm_num     | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    | allow_comm   | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
    | allow_main   | tinyint(1) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | 1                   |                |
    | approve      | tinyint(1)            | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    | fixed        | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
    | allow_br     | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
    | symbol       | varchar(3)            | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | tags         | varchar(255)          | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
    | metatitle    | varchar(255)          | NO   |     |                     |                |
    | FileTempUUID | varchar(11)           | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    +--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

post_category;

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid        | bigint(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| postId     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| categoryId | smallint(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What is in the value of `{$join}`?

Comment: Until we dont know your db structure it difficult to guess

Comment: Please separate the SQL from PHP (i.e. *only* show the SQL and structure of relations). How the PHP generates this SQL is irrelevant to how SQL will perform the join (if it generates it incorrectly, then that's merely a bug in the code and has nothing to do with SQL or the join). So, in the end: *show the actual SQL [intended to be] executed*.

Comment: Have a look at [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query)

Comment: [And Q&A here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407266/mysqli-inner-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your tables schema, Try this join:

```
SELECT 
    p.* 
FROM 
    post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_category c ON (c.postId = p.id)
WHERE 
    c.categoryId IN (125,3) AND p.approve=1
GROUP BY p.id
```

Also using `GROUP BY p.id` to distinct posts, if needed.

Comment: @hallaji I believe this should be left Join to return all the posts

Answer (score 0):

I think the Variable {$join} refers to the string This is totally Wrong, There is special Keyword called Join in SQL, I will try Hardly to write SQL Statement to do what I guessed that u want

```
$sql = "Select a.postId, a.categoryId, b.* from post_category a, post b where a.postId = b.id and (a.categoryId='125' or a.categoryId='3')
```

@Edit
If i understood ur comment your code would result in this

```
 SELECT * FROM post select distinct postId 
  from post_category 
  where categoryId='125' or categoryId='3' AND approve=1"
```

Which is totally wrong SQL Statement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT postId post.* FROM post_category 
LEFT JOIN post ON post_category.postId = post.id
WHERE (categoryId='125' OR categoryId='3') AND post.approve = 1
```